# Can you please tell me how to rename ionic apk name

Tags: angular, ionic2

can you please tell me how to rename the apk name to my project name "Test" using ionic3.

I have create a ionic angular project.when i build the apk for android.it is generating with app.debug.apk name.

can you tell me the steps how to name that app.debug.apk  to Test.apk ?

Comment: The apk name is not really important.. You can rename it as renaming a file. The real app id is your package name

Answer (score 2):

First you need to change config.xml

```
<widget id="your app id" version="your app version" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>Your app name</name>
    <description>your app desc</description>
    <author email="your e-mail" href="link to your website">developer name or website name</author>
```

After that you just rename released version by renaming it into what you want.
Furthermore, your debug apk is not your release apk. You need to run command:

```
ionic cordova build android --prod --release
```

Comment: can you please tell me what will be the app id i want to given.

Comment: If your app is just for testing, app id can be test.1, app version 1.0.0. If you plan on uploading app to google play, than you app id must be unique because you can't upload apk with same app id to google play store.

Comment: <widget id="test.1" version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>Flight Key</name>
    <description>Flight Key</description>.I have changed config.xml like above.But when i build it is not building the apk for me

Comment: during the time of building it is showing the error like below
(node:1276) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Error: Invalid attribute name
Line: 4
Column: 42

Comment: Check line four and what you wrote there.